# Вывести данные в частичном представлении Razor MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor

Не могу разобраться как передать данные из контролера в частичное представление и вывести их.

Есть контролер Holiday который выводит данные в таблицу:

```
public IActionResult Holiday()
{
    IEnumerable<SocialSession> socialSession = _context.SocialSession
         .Include(p => p.RestPlace)
             .ThenInclude(t => t.RestWay)
             .ThenInclude(x => x.RestPeriod)
             .ThenInclude(z => z.SocialWay)
         .Include(a => a.SocialDelivery)
         .ToList();

    return View(socialSession);
}
```

Есть его View Holiday:

```
@model IEnumerable<Domain.Models.SocialSession>;
@foreach (var item in Model) { 
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
    </td>
    <td>
        <a asp-action="Create" asp-route- id="@item.Id">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RestPlace.Name)</a>
    </td>
```

Контролер Create в котором нужно вывести данные полученные из View Holiday:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(decimal id)
{
    var docType = await _context.TypeDocs.ToListAsync();
    ViewBag.docType = new SelectList(docType, "Id", "TypeDocName");
    var school = await _context.School.ToListAsync();
    ViewBag.school = new SelectList(school, "Id", "AbbName");

    if(id != 0 && id != null)
    {
        var places = await _context.SocialPlace.ToListAsync();
        var place = places.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);
        PartialView("HolidayForm", place);
    }
    return View();
}
```

View Create:

```
@model Domain.DTOs.Person.Create.PersonSocialChildDto;
    <div class="col-md-12 border rounded">
        @Html.Partial("HolidayForm")
    </div>
```

И частичное представление HolidayForm:

```
@model Domain.Models.SocialPlace;

    <div class="input-group">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroupUsername" placeholder="место отдыха">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <div class="input-group">
                <a asp-action="Holiday" class="btn btn-success">...</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Comments" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Comments" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Comments" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Мне нужно что-бы при клике по ссылке во View Holiday данные передавались в контролер Create и отрисовывались в частичном представлении "HolidayForm" в поле Name и Comments.

Если создаю отдельный контролер с отдельной View, то все работает как и надо.

Но если данные передаю в контролер "Create", то на View ошибка

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Domain.Models.SocialPlace', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'Domain.DTOs.Person.Create.PersonSocialChildDto'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому интересно, то решение такое: 
Принимает в контролере id и находим нужную информацию

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(SocialPlace socialPlace)
    {
        if(socialPlace.Id != 0)
        {
            var places = await _context.SocialPlace.ToListAsync();
            var place = places.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == socialPlace.Id);
            ViewBag.HolidayName = place.Name;
        }

        return View();

    }
```

Потом через ViewBag выводим информацию в частичное представление

```
<input asp-for="Name" value="@ViewBag.HolidayName"  class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroupUsername">
```